# Geometrical Derivation of the Polar Unit Vector?

Tags: geometry, vector-analysis, spherical-coordinates

Does anyone know what is wrong with my derivation of the polar unit vector, $\vec{e}_{\theta}$? [My Derivation](https://derive-it.com/2021/03/28/the-polar-unit-vector/?fbclid=IwAR1RI5Ay9AFPRpAknR0wiMYUakl4GPe7HWjpBEA7txQQln9_jA1JChGkAuA) does not match [Wikipedia's Result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). Alternatively, do you know how to derive the polar unit vector in spherical coordinates from a geometrical standpoint?

Comment: Note that $e_\theta$ is rotating $e_r$ by $\pi/2$ in the plane containing $0$, $z$-axis and your point, so $e_z\cdot e_\theta=\cos(\theta+\pi/2)$, etc.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I am going to fix my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\vec e_\theta$ in terms of $\vec e_z$ and your $\vec e_w,$

$$
\vec e_\theta = (\cos \theta) \vec e_w - (\sin\theta) \vec e_z.
$$

What you wrote for this step is incorrect, as you should be able to verify by taking $\theta$ near $0.$
In that case $\cos\theta \approx 1$ and $\sin\theta \approx 0,$ so your formula would result in $\vec e_\theta \approx -\vec e_z.$
Should $\vec e_\theta$ point almost straight down when $\theta$ is very small?

The formula in Wikipedia is consistent with the formula in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in the very first step.  You got your $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ swapped.